# Moving a small C++ project from XCode to Visual studio. Ceiling/floor unrecognized?

Tags: c++

I have a small c++ project I've been working on in XCode, that I'd like to do some work with on my Windows machine, on Visual Studio.  I made a new project and copied all of the source files into the new project.  There are no external dependencies.

Now, Visual Studio does not like any of my floor or ceil calls.  I get the following compiler error for every call to ceil or floor.

> 'ceil': ambiguous call to overloaded
>   function

These functions are not overloaded, and I've imported math.h in the header file to this .cpp file.  What gives?

Comment: We'd need to see the usage. For one thing, you should almost certainly be importing `<cmath>` instead of `<math.h>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a collision between std::ceil and ceil (if you use an evil **using namespace std**). 
*-> Remove the using namespace and add std:: in front of every occurence.*

It is possible that the compiler doesn't know which version of **ceil** to use ceil(float foo) or ceil(double foo).

*-> Check if the arguments of your call are well typed.*

Comment: Is there a `ceil()` template in C++?

Comment: There is no `std::ceil()` template so the second part of your answer is strange. But +1 for the first part

Answer (score 1):

The compiler found several versions of 'ceil' and want you to tell it which one to use.
Use the preprocessor to find out where it got 'ceil' from and fix your includes.

Example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/ceil/

```
/* ceil example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
  printf ("ceil of 2.3 is %.1lf\n", ceil (2.3) );
  printf ("ceil of 3.8 is %.1lf\n", ceil (3.8) );
  printf ("ceil of -2.3 is %.1lf\n", ceil (-2.3) );
  printf ("ceil of -3.8 is %.1lf\n", ceil (-3.8) );
  return 0;
}
```

Or better C++

```
/* ceil example */
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

int main ()
{
  printf ("ceil of 2.3 is %.1lf\n", std::ceil (2.3) );
  printf ("ceil of 3.8 is %.1lf\n", std::ceil (3.8) );
  printf ("ceil of -2.3 is %.1lf\n", std::ceil (-2.3) );
  printf ("ceil of -3.8 is %.1lf\n", std::ceil (-3.8) );
  return 0;
}
```